# Error handling using `Deferred`

Tags: jquery

`Deferred` objects have two main pools of callbacks, namely `doneCallbacks` and `failCallbacks`. Both pools are "linear": the callbacks are stored one after the other in the order they were given in.

This linear structure seems to go against the "tree-like" structure one has to consider when  handling errors. At every step, there are two cases: fail and pass.

```
if(err) {
     // stuff
     if(err) {
          // stuff
     } else {
          // stuff
     }
else {
     // stuff
     if(err) {
          // stuff
     } else {
          // stuff
     }
}
```

It seems that because of the imposed linearity of `Deferred`s, they are not very suited for error handling. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit wordy but this is from the jQuery documentation for `$.when()`:

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when,
>   the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object
>   that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been
>   passed. **The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the
>   Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the
>   Deferreds is rejected.** If the master Deferred is resolved, it is
>   passed the resolved values of all the Deferreds that were passed to
>   jQuery.when. For example, when the Deferreds are jQuery.ajax()
>   requests, the arguments will be the jqXHR objects for the requests, in
>   the order they were given in the argument list.
>
> **In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected,
>   jQuery.when immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master
>   Deferred.** Note that some of the Deferreds may still be unresolved at
>   that point. If you need to perform additional processing for this
>   case, such as canceling any unfinished ajax requests, you can keep
>   references to the underlying jqXHR objects in a closure and
>   inspect/cancel them in the failCallback.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/*

So if a `deferred` object resolves to an error then the `master deferred` fires `failCallbacks` and it's up to you to decide what to do with the possibly un-resolved `deferred`s.